# How to extract the 100th max in Quicksight calculated field

Tags: dax, amazon-quicksight

How do you retrieve the 100th highest **{price_in_euro}** data?

So I have this diagram that shows the highest-priced cars in various auctions in 2004-22. I need to show how different the highest price, 100th price, 250th price, and 1000th price are.

I have easily created a calculated field that goes like **max({price_in_euro})**, how do I create the rest?

Answer (score 0):

You can get Nth largest or smallest value by using RANK function in the calculated field and filtering over the column.

your_calc_field = rank([{price_in_euro} DESC],[], PRE_AGG)

- Desc == descending, ranks 1 for the largest value
- [] == empty list, SQL partition by equivalent
- PRE_AGG == calculation level value, what it does: apply ranking before aggregating the results. Otherwise, with the default value of POST_AGG, quicksight raises an error for disaggregated ranking.

For further information, [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/rank-function.html)

Comment: I apologize but this one is a bit misleading for me.

How exactly do you mean I retrieve the 100th largest one here? Could you please provide me the exact formula?